# How to enable bracket navigation in evil mode?

Tags: evil

Vim mode has `[` `]` keys to navigate brackets.

[See this example.](https://superuser.com/a/311737/240907)

Eg, selecting a comment block can be done this way in vim:

`[/` `v`, `%`

Is this possible in emacs with evil mode?

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't been implemented in Evil yet, no. You can see what has been implemented so far by using `F1 k [`.